# Default custom post type url

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, rewrite-rules

I have created a custom post type with the following base slug `sections`.

```
public static function post_type_register_sections() {
    global $slug;

    $labels = array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __('Sections'),
            'singular_name' => __('Sections'),
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'rewrite'   => array('slug' => $slug),
        'has_archive' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => false,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar' => false,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-visibility',
        'supports' => array('title', 'excerpt', 'page-attributes')
    );

    register_post_type('makeup_section', $labels);
}
```

Now when i create other posts, with any url, since i have `hierarchical` set to true, it prepends, which is what i want.

```
localhost:3005/en/sections/test
localhost:3005/en/sections/test/child
```

Any of the following urls above work fine, i get the desired `$post`.
But when i want to visit the root, `localhost:3005/en/sections/` it returns me a `$post` even tho one is not assign. Is there any way to validate this? Since when i want to visit the base `localhost:3005/en/sections/` i don't want it to return me any `$post`.

`localhost:3005/en/sections/` return me the `$post` from   `localhost:3005/en/sections/test`.

I have tried setting the `rewrite` to `array('with_front' => false)` but it doesn't recognize the child urls.

===EDIT===

This is the base post register type that shows in the menu admin

`post_type_register_sections` from above is a child to this.

```
public static function post_type_register()
{
    $labels = array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __('MakeUp'),
            'singular_name' => __('MakeUp'),
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'show_in_admin_bar' => false,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-art',
        'supports' => array('title', 'excerpt'),
    );
    register_post_type('makeup', $labels);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You set `'has_archive' => true`, which will make your post type archive URL `localhost:3005/en/makeup_section/`, as it will use your post type slug if you do not specify a string.

Change it to `'has_archive' => 'sections'` to place it at `localhost:3005/en/sections/`.

Comment: i changed `'has_archive' => 'sections'` but when i load `localhost:3005/en/sections/` it is still redirecting me to some other post. I have deactivated-activated the plugin, anything i would need to do?

Comment: have you flushed rewrite rules?

Comment: yeah just did that

Comment: i also have another post type registered, i don't know if its irrelevant, i will update the question with the code